# Could I set a scenario to start by default using MS Health BOT Service?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am using Microsoft Health BOT Service. And I want to display a welcome message to the users and ask them to choose one of our prompts (select one from a list of choices).

To do that, I think to do one of those options:

1. Is there any way to display prompts in `Automatic welcome message`?
2. If I create a scenario to display this message, can I mark it to be the default scenario? So if I deploy the bot to the `web-chat` or other channel, the scenario will be started **without** waiting for an input from the user.

can I do something like that?

Comment: 1. Yes. You should be able to display whatever you want in the welcome message. Are you able to get any text message to show in automatic welcome?